# Object Detection with RetinaNet(Keras) the model does not make any detection

Tags: keras, computer-vision, object-detection, bounding-box, retinanet

I ran the Retinanet [tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/) on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/retinanet.ipynb) but in the prediction phase, the model does not make any detections and no bounding box is displayed on the images.

any help please

I displayed the content of the "detections" variable (detections = inference_model.predict(input_image)) and all values are equal to zero.